# event listener to execute a function when html content is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to add an event listener to check and execute some jquery function when an html content is not empty.  I have a div content in my page which will be shown only after the execution of a click(funcion()); ie, when the click function is executed the returned value will be shown in the above said div content and the div will be shown.
Here's my html content which is previously hidden,

```
<div id="tapal_doc_Form" class="tapal_form" style="width:97%">
  <legend id="legend_tapal"><h2>Upolad Tapal Documents for <label class="tapal_head" id="ret_tapal_id"></label>:</h2> </legend> 
  <div id="multifileupload">Upload</div>
</div>
```

The function goes here,

```
$("#sendButton").click(function(){   
var ajax_data = {
    Tdist:$("#Tdist").val(),
    Tno_curr : $("#Tno_curr").val(),
    Tyear : $("#Tyear").val(),
    Trec_date : $("#Trec_date").val(),
};
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('tapal/insert_new_tapal'); ?>",
    type: 'POST', 
    data: ajax_data,
    success: function(result) {
        $("#tapal_entry_form").hide();
        if(result==1){
            $("#msg_doc_upload").html("Tapal entered successfully");
        }else if(result==0){
            $("#msg_doc_upload").html("Tapal could not be registered!");
        }else{
            $("#tapal_doc_Form").show();    
            $("#ret_tapal_id").empty();
            $("#ret_tapal_id").html(result);
        }
    }       
});
});
```

And the listener function ,

```
    var settings = {
    url: "<?php echo site_url('tapal/document_upload'); ?>",
    method: "POST",
    allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif,doc,pdf,zip",
    formData:{tapal_id: $("#ret_tapal_id").html(), file_type:'TAPALS' },
    fileName: "myfile",
    multiple: true,
    onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
    {
        $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload is success</font>");
    },
    onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
    {       
        $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload is Failed</font>");
    }
    }
  $("#multiplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);
```

Now, when the 'click' function returns the 'tapal_id' to my label 'ret_tapal_id', i am not getting that value to listener function. The listener still passes null value.
So i need to execute the listener when the first function returns the value to the label 'ret_tapal_id' or when the label is not empty.
Please help me. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be because your ajax call is not getting completed and you are uploading before it. That may be due to asynchronous behavior of ajax. So either you can wait for ajax to complete or call your `.uploadFile()` after you set the html of it in your ajax success function:

```
success: function(result) {
    $("#tapal_entry_form").hide();
    if(result==1){
        $("#msg_doc_upload").html("Tapal entered successfully");
    }else if(result==0){
        $("#msg_doc_upload").html("Tapal could not be registered!");
    }else{
        $("#tapal_doc_Form").show();    
        $("#ret_tapal_id").empty();
        $("#ret_tapal_id").html(result); // add your method after this.

        var settings = {
             url: "<?php echo site_url('tapal/document_upload'); ?>",
             method: "POST",
             allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif,doc,pdf,zip",
             formData:{tapal_id: $("#ret_tapal_id").html(), file_type:'TAPALS' },
             fileName: "myfile",
             multiple: true,
             onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
             {
               $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload is success</font>");
             },
             onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
             {       
               $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload is Failed</font>");
             }
         }
         $("#multiplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);  

    } // else ends
} // success ends
```

Comment: if any answer solved your issue then you have to accept it as an answer to your question asked here @ SO.